# Load spring context EAR avoiding web.xml configuration

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I have an enterprise application packaged as:

EAR

- WAR1
- WAR2
- ejb.jar
- lib/core.jar
- lib/module1.jar
- lib/module2.jar
- ...
- lib/moduleN.jar

*WAR* packages are optional and every *moduleX.jar* contains a *spring-bean.xml* configuration file.

I need to load the spring context in the ***core.jar*** and share this context between *WARs*. Since i don't know how many modules are packaged, i need to load the xml files at runtime.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Do u want to share a spring context with different ear s at runtime? why do u need something like this?

Comment: @Neron sorry, it's a mistake. I need to share the context between WARs.

Comment: As I know, each war creates it's own context. SO it seems not right in this case. But you can always use same xml file for both wars.